# Choosing motor speeds for an omnidirectional robot given desired linear and angular velocity

Tags: velocity, angular-velocity

Below is an example of an "omnidirectional robot" with four wheels.  Each wheel has rollers on it so it can only exert a force along the line parallel to its face, coincident to the ground, and coincident with the point on the wheel touching the ground.

[image]

I am trying to choose angular velocities for each of the four motors to result in a desired 2D linear velocity vector as well as an angular velocity for the whole robot.  For simplicity, I have reduced this problem to the following diagram, where each wheel contributes a velocity vector to the system with magnitude $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ respectively.

Note that this is kind of like an extended force diagram, but I can only control motor velocity (speed and direction), and so it doesn't make sense to use forces for my application.

The vector $[x, y]$ is the desired instantaneous velocity vector (fixed to the robot), and $\omega$ is the desired instantaneous angular velocity.

[image]

Say the distance of each wheel from the center of the robot is constant $r$.  Then, I believe
\begin{align*}
\omega=\frac{a+b+c+d}{4r}\\
\end{align*}

Also, $x=(c-a)$ and $y=(b-d)$.

Therefore, $a=(c-x)$, $b=(d+y)$, $c=(a+x)$, and $d=(b-y)$.  Substituting into the equation for $\omega$, we have:

\begin{align*}
\omega&=\frac{a+b+c+d}{4r}\\
&=\frac{(c-x)+b+c+(b-y)}{4r}\\
4r\omega&=2(c+b)-x-y\\
\frac{4r\omega+x+y}{2}&=c+b\\
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
\omega&=\frac{a+b+c+d}{4r}\\
&=\frac{a+(d+y)+(a+x)+d}{4r}\\
4r\omega&=2(a+d)+x+y\\
\frac{4r\omega-x-y}{2}&=a+d\\
\end{align*}

Since everything on the left side of these two equations is given, we can introduce constants $m$ and $n$, where $m=\frac{4r\omega-x-y}{2}$ and $n=\frac{4r\omega+x+y}{2}$.  Then, we simply have $a+d=m$ and $b+c=n$.

I then proceeded to find the values of $a$ and $b$ such that the squared differences between each motor value and the average motor value were minimized.  I did this because each motor has a max speed, and so if max$(a,b,c,d)$ were above that max speed I would have to multiply all of the motor speeds by $\bigg( \frac{\text{max power}}{\text{max}(a,b,c,d)} \bigg)$.  This would keep the direction of the desired vectors, but would reduce the magnitudes to be attainable.  Minimizing the sum of the squared deviances should minimize the amount that I will have to scale down all of the speeds.
 In other words, I minimized the following with respect to $a$ and $b$:

\begin{align*}
&\hspace{0.6cm} (a-\text{avg})^2+(b-\text{avg})^2+(c-\text{avg})^2+(d-\text{avg})^2 \\\\
&=(a-\tfrac{a+b+c+d}{4})^2+(b-\tfrac{a+b+c+d}{4})^2+(c-\tfrac{a+b+c+d}{4})^2+d-\tfrac{a+b+c+d}{4})^2 \\\\ 
&=(a-\tfrac{a+b+(n-b)+(m-a)}{4})^2+(b-\tfrac{a+b+(n-b)+(m-a)}{4})^2+((n-b)-\tfrac{a+b+(n-b)+(m-a)}{4})^2+((m-a)-\tfrac{a+b+(n-b)+(m-a)}{4})^2 \\\\
\end{align*}

If you do out the partials (or [use](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=minimize%20(a-%5Ctfrac%7Ba%2Bb%2B(n-b)%2B(m-a)%7D%7B4%7D)%5E2%2B(b-%5Ctfrac%7Ba%2Bb%2B(n-b)%2B(m-a)%7D%7B4%7D)%5E2%2B((n-b)-%5Ctfrac%7Ba%2Bb%2B(n-b)%2B(m-a)%7D%7B4%7D)%5E2%2B((m-a)-%5Ctfrac%7Ba%2Bb%2B(n-b)%2B(m-a)%7D%7B4%7D)%5E2%20with%20respect%20to%20a%20and%20b) Wolfram Alpha) you get $a=\frac{m}{2}$ and $b=\frac{n}{2}$, and then you can solve for $c=\frac{n}{2}$ and $d=\frac{m}{2}$.

The problem is, when I test this out, I get a peculiar result.  If I plug in $x=100$, $y=0$, and $\omega=100$, I get $m=(200r-50)$ and $n=(200r+50)$.  So using my previously derived formulae, $[a,b,c,d]=[100r-25,100r+25,100r+25,100r-25]$ which works when plugged into the equations $a+d=m$ and $b+c
=n$, but yields $[x,y,\omega]=[50,50,100]\neq [100,0,100]$.  Are the steps to get (a+d) and (b+c) in terms of $x$, $y$, and $\omega$ not reversible?  How can I attain my goal?

Comment: You're going to have to have a time dependence in your wheels. If the robot rotates, $a$ is no longer aligned with the x-axis, for example...

Comment: I should have specified, but I just want x and y fixed to the robot... so the x, y, and $\omega$ are instantaneous and the x-y axes change moment to moment

Comment: This article discusses how to do this relative to a fixed set of axes: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/324929202_Motion_Improvement_of_Four-Wheeled_Omnidirectional_Mobile_Robots_for_Indoor_Terrain

Comment: I was hoping to keep the axes relative because I ultimately want the robot to be able to turn around a point so I need $\omega$=x/R where R is the radius from the point to the center of the robot... assuming the y axis is pointed at the object

Comment: I think this is better for the engineering site , there are various in stackechange. this is the general https://engineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I don’t think $4\,r$ term is correct. The units of x is meter but a and c are velocity?

Comment: @Eli the units of x are actually m/s